# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout how can solve it below is my code

Tags: android

```
public void getResponseForAllMilkHistory(Response response)
    {
//        Log.e("Response", "inside getResponseForAllMilkHistory ");

        Log.e("Response", "In response");
        JSONObject jsonobject = null;
        try{
            //ArrayList<MilkDbModel> data=new ArrayList<>();
            if (response.getIs_success()){
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(response.getData());
                Log.e("check", jsonobject.toString());
                MilkDbModel dbData=new MilkDbModel();
                dbData.milk_id=jsonobject.getInt("milk_id");
                dbData.shop_name=jsonobject.getString("shop_name");
                dbData.date=jsonobject.getString("date");
                dbData.shift=jsonobject.getString("shift");
                dbData.cow_milk=jsonobject.getDouble("cow_milk");
                dbData.buffalo_milk=jsonobject.getDouble("buffalo_milk");
                dbData.cow_milk_price=jsonobject.getDouble("cow_milk_price");
              dbData.buffalo_milk_price=jsonobject.getDouble("buffalo_milk_price");

            }else{
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(response.getData());
                    Log.e("error", jsonobject.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Where is your recycleview code ??

Comment: This is onCreate()

Comment: @ tahsinRupam, can u post your recycleview code?

Comment: ecyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: No, this is not onCreate(). You are parsing json response in above code. Show your onCreate where you initiated recycleview.

Comment: Edit your question ans add full activity code. Don't add code as comments.

Comment: when adapter is not set and no items passed to adapter you get this message in log cat where you no need to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your onCreate

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); 
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recyclerView .setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
 YourAdapter_Class adapter= new YourAdapter_Class(arraylist/linklist or whatever parameter is);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and when you parse data then notify adapter like this

```
recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: @kirans, Let me know if there is any problem

Comment: @ kirans, please accept the answer if works so that other person can use it.